# RestTemplate - POST request for resulted in 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I try to implement custom Auth Server and Client. I use as example [this code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples). I modified Tonr2 application to not to use any users. I want to convert this 2 application. Tonr2 should create session of user based on session from Sparklr2. Now I modified this parts:

In Sparklr2 (ResourceConfiguration class):

```
@Bean
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails sparklr() {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails details = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        details.setId("sparklr/tonr");
        details.setClientId("tonr");
        details.setClientSecret("secret");
        details.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
        details.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.query);
        details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
        details.setScope(Arrays.asList("read", "write"));
        return details;
    }
```

In Tonr2:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
// I removed all users
//  @Override
//  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("marissa").password("wombat").roles("USER").and().withUser("sam")
//              .password("kangaroo").roles("USER");
//  }

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/sparklr/**").permitAll();
}

}
```

And:

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
     clients.inMemory().withClient("tonr")
                .resourceIds(SPARKLR_RESOURCE_ID)
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
                        //.authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .secret("secret");
```

But I got:

```
RestTemplate - POST request for "http://localhost:8080/sparklr2/oauth/token" resulted in 401 (Unauthorized); invoking error handler
error="access_denied", error_description="Error requesting access token."
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:145)
```

How to fix it? Or maybe you have some example how to do this properly?

Comment: Hey i have the same issue... did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @NeoP5 yes, I solved this. it's a lot of info. If you still need this - contact me alex.bishop@yandex.ru